# WHM - Console not working

Tags: linux, centos, putty, whm

I have VPS with  CENTOS 6.4 x86_64 virtuozzo – vps9458 and WHM 11.34.1 (build 14). I am trying to connect server by Putty but I am only getting below error:

**server unexpectedly closed network connection**

My WHM url look like this 1.2.3.5:2087 and in putty I am using 1.2.3.5 as Host name and 2087 as port. I always see error above.

Please guide what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually connecting via putty using SSH you will need to be on port 22. So try port 22 instead.

2087 is for cpanel/whm and is meant for the web browser only.

If it still doesn't work email your web hosting provider.